# Jwt token generation in mulesoft dwl for RS512

Tags: jwt, dataweave, mule4

Can anyone help me on how to create a JWT token based on RS512 algorithm?
Provided I have both private and public key.

I know how to create for HS256 algorithm, but need to know how can I create for RS512.

code snippet for HS256:

```
import * from dw::Crypto
import * from dw::core::Binaries
import * from dw::core::URL
var header = "{\"alg\":\"HS256\",\"typ\":\"JWT\"}"
var payload = "{\"sub\":\"15081947\",\"name\":\"Hello\",\"iat\":1516239022}"
var secret_key = "1234567890"
fun base64encodeURL(data) = toBase64(data) replace "/" with("_") replace "+" with("-") replace "=" with ""
---
using (header_encoded = base64encodeURL(header),
  payload_encoded = base64encodeURL(payload),
  mixed = header_encoded ++ "." ++ payload_encoded
)
mixed ++ "." ++ base64encodeURL(HMACBinary(secret_key as Binary, mixed as Binary, "HmacSHA256"))
```

This gives me jwt token for HS256., I need help on generating token for RS512

Comment: Are you using this project as baseline? https://github.com/mulesoft/data-weave-jwt-library

Comment: This project uses asserts, may i know if it can be used in dw (playground) - coz I have seen in few blogs mentioning asserts can be used only in munits

Comment: This library does not work on the Playground as it requires Java classes

Answer (score 1):

[This library](https://github.com/mulesoft/data-weave-jwt-library) you can find on [Exchange](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913/data-weave-jwt-library/) supports [RS512](https://github.com/mulesoft/data-weave-jwt-library/blob/master/src/main/dw/jwt/RSA.dwl#L7)